# Java IPv6 Address String to Bytes

Tags: java, string, encoding, byte, ipv6

How can I convert a String containing the ipv6's machine packet destination to a 16 byte array? I know about getBytes and encodings, but I can't seem to understand which encoding I should use or if I have to convert that String to Hexadecimal or not.

```
String ipv6 = "2001:0DB8:AC10:FE01:0000:0000:0000:0000";
byte[] bytes = ipv6.getBytes(); //must be a 16 byte array
```

An example of what I wanna do, just to exemplify. 
Obs.: I have to convert the String to a 16 byte array
Thanks

Answer (score 22):

try this

```
    InetAddress a = InetAddress.getByName("2001:0DB8:AC10:FE01:0000:0000:0000:0000");
    byte[] bytes = a.getAddress();
```

Answer (score 1):

[The open-source IPAddress Java library](https://seancfoley.github.io/IPAddress/) will handle a wide range of IPv6addresses, so it can be used if your string need validation or has a wide variety of formats.  Disclaimer: I am the project manager of that library.

Example code:

```
String ipv6 = "::1";
try {
    IPAddressString str = new IPAddressString("::1");
    IPAddress addr = str.toAddress();
    byte[] bytes = addr.getBytes();`
} catch(IPAddressStringException e) {
    //e.getMessage has validation error
}
```