# Java: Manual conversion of string IPv6 address to byte array

Tags: java, arrays, string

I need to do a manual conversion of a string representation of IPv6 to a byte array. I'm on an embedded device and don't have access to external libraries.

For example:

```
String addr_str = "bbbb::1"
```

with manual conversion would be:

```
byte[] addr = new byte[]{(byte) 187,(byte) 187,0,0 //187 == bb
                                ,0,0,0,0
                                ,0,0,0,0
                                ,0,0,0,1};
```

Ideally, I would like to create a function, like 'convertToIPv6ByteArray', that would enable:

```
addr = convertToIPv6ByteArray(addr_str);
```

I'm having difficulties implementing this function efficiently though. Any help?

Comment: Maybe look at this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17267670/java-ipv6-address-string-to-bytes
And here is the implementation 
http://developer.classpath.org/doc/java/net/InetAddress-source.html

Easiest way would be just copy the source code of the this class to your project if you can If you can add the libraries :D or you can look into the implementation and and reimplement it.

Comment: @user1097772 add this as an answer to get it accepted :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this: [Java IPv6 Address String to Bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17267670/java-ipv6-address-string-to-bytes) 
And here is the implementation http://developer.classpath.org/doc/java/net/InetAddress-source.html 
 
Options to do: 
Easiest way would be just copy the source code of the this class to your project if you can if you can not add the libraries.
  Or you can look into the implementation and reimplement it.