# How to convert ipv6 string address into 16 bytes?

Tags: java

I want to create `InetAddress` using `InetAddress.getByAddress(byte[])` due to avoid looking up.
my Ipv6 address is like  `fe80::59eb:9920:1139:6dd3%4` or `fe80:0000:0000:0000:59eb:9920:1139:6dd3%4`
as per java document it should be 16 byte ,it has 8 block. it seems that every block should be convert to 2 bytes and  how to do it ?

i checked following link [Java IPv6 Address String to Bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17267670/java-ipv6-address-string-to-bytes)

they suggested to do like

```
  InetAddress a = InetAddress.getByName("2001:0DB8:AC10:FE01:0000:0000:0000:0000");
    byte[] bytes = a.getAddress();
```

this is not help as `InetAddress.getByName()` will do lookup and may block right?

**update:**

I am new to byte work on java. i am guessing

16 byte so,

In 128 binary format, every character of ipv6 address (left to right or right to left ??) added with "|" . then will get output

or

In 128 bit binary format, left shift to all charactor like

**Example:** 
(f)0000 (e)0000 (8)0000 (0)0000 etc

i am not sure. i am more confused with this concept

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: @MOnkey i  updated question

Comment: From [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/net/InetAddress.html#getByName%28java.lang.String%29): “If a literal IP address is supplied, only the validity of the address format is checked.”

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you’re wrong. The suggested way is correct and works.

```
    InetAddress a = InetAddress.getByName("fe80::59eb:9920:1139:6dd3%4");
    byte[] bytes = a.getAddress();
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(bytes));
```

Output is:

> [-2, -128, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 89, -21, -103, 32, 17, 57, 109, -45]

If you give `getByName()` an IP name (like `ajax.com`), it will perform IP lookup. If you give it the IP number as in the code example, it won’t. From then documentation:

> If a literal IP address is supplied, only the validity of the address
>   format is checked.

([Documentation of `InetAddress.getByName()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#getByName(java.lang.String)))

The negative numbers in the output may surprise. In Java a byte is always a signed number. So bytes that we may think of as lying between 128 and 255 inclusive come out as -128 through -1.